# Image gallery - inline height value in <li>

Tags: 7, theming, media

I'm using Drupal's Image module to generate a basic image gallery, it works fine for my client's needs but for some reason, it assigns a height value to each `<li>` in the image gallery as an inline style. It is not clear to me how it is coming up with this value, or how I can alter this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: this 'height value' is in descendent/ascendent way? how is assigned that value, by hand in content type, or automatically according first/last results?

Comment: What is the version of Drupal you are running?